# Find the element with highest occurrences in an array [java]

Tags: java

I have to find the element with highest occurrences in a double array.
I did it like this:

```
int max = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
       int count = 0;
       for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
         if (array[i]==array[j])
             count++;
   }
  if (count >= max)
      max = count;
 }
```

The program works, but it is too slow! I have to find a better solution, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update:**

- As Maxim pointed out, using [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) would be a more appropriate choice than [Hashtable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) here.
- The assumption here is that you are not concerned with concurrency. If synchronized access is needed, use [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) instead.

---

You can use a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) to count the occurrences of each unique element in your double array, and that would:

- Run in linear **O(n)** time, and
- Require **O(n)** space

**Psuedo code** would be something like this:

- Iterate through all of the elements of your array once: **O(n)**

  - For each element visited, check to see if its key already exists in the HashMap: **O(1), amortized**
  - If it does not (first time seeing this element), then add it to your HashMap as [key: this element, value: 1]. **O(1)**
  - If it does exist, then increment the value corresponding to the key by 1. **O(1), amortized**
- Having finished building your HashMap, iterate through the map and find the key with the highest associated value - and that's the element with the highest occurrence. **O(n)**

**A partial code solution** to give you an idea how to use HashMap:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
...

    HashMap hm = new HashMap();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        Double key = new Double(array[i]);
        if ( hm.containsKey(key) ) {
            value = hm.get(key);
            hm.put(key, value + 1);
        } else {
            hm.put(key, 1);
        }
    }
```

I'll leave as an exercise for how to iterate through the HashMap afterwards to find the key with the highest value; but if you get stuck, just add another comment and I'll get you more hints =)

Comment: @sampson-chen I think use `HashMap` instead `HashTable` since `HashTable` is thread-safe and performance degradation

Comment: @MaximShoustin oh, that's right, `Hashtable` is going to be deprecated by `ConcurrentHashMap`, no?

Comment: @sampson-chen true, ConcurrentHashMap.

Comment: btw, you have `Collections.frequency`. To do not reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: i've created a collection from the HashMap and i've iterated through this collection =)

Comment: i've tried also the Collections.frequency method... but it takes much more time than the HashMap method :)

Answer (score 7):

Use `Collections.frequency` option:

```
 List<String> list = Arrays.asList("1", "1","1","1","1","1","5","5","12","12","12","12","12","12","12","12","12","12","8");
      int max = 0;
      int curr = 0;
      String currKey =  null;
      Set<String> unique = new HashSet<String>(list);

          for (String key : unique) {
                curr = Collections.frequency(list, key);

               if(max < curr){
                 max = curr;
                 currKey = key;
                }
            }

          System.out.println("The number "  + currKey + " happens " + max + " times");
```

Output:

`The number 12 happens 10 times`

Comment: This code won't work with negative values. Thank you

Comment: Negative values of what?

Answer (score 6):

The solution with Java 8

```
       int result = Arrays.stream(array)
           .boxed()
           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i->i,Collectors.counting()))
           .values()
           .stream()
           .max(Comparator.comparingLong(i->i))
           .orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new));
```

Answer (score 5):

I will suggest another method. I don't know if this would work faster or not.

Quick sort the array. Use the built in Arrays.sort() method.

Now compare the adjacent elements. 
Consider this example:

1 1 1 1 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 9 9 9 10 10 10 29 29 29 29 29 29

When the adjacent elements are not equal, you can stop counting that element.

Comment: What would be the time and space complexity of this method, compared to the one accepted as an answer? which one´s best?

Comment: @DanielPerez Time complexity: O(N log N), Space: O(log N). Accepted answer has the advantage that it doesn't modify the original array and that it would be considerably faster on large arrays, although it would do take up more space.

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1: Using HashMap

```
class test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] a = {1,1,2,1,5,6,6,6,8,5,9,7,1};
    // max occurences of an array
    Map<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
      int max = 0 ; int chh = 0 ;
      for(int i = 0 ; i < a.length;i++) {
          int ch = a[i];
          map.put(ch, map.getOrDefault(ch, 0) +1);
      }//for
      Set<Entry<Integer,Integer>> entrySet =map.entrySet();

      for(Entry<Integer,Integer> entry : entrySet) {
          if(entry.getValue() > max) {max = entry.getValue();chh = entry.getKey();}

      }//for
    System.out.println("max element => " + chh);
    System.out.println("frequency => " + max);
    }//amin
}
/*output =>
max element => 1
frequency => 4

*/
```

Solution 2 : Using count array

```
public class test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         int[] a = {1,1,2,1,5,6,6,6,6,6,8,5,9,7,1};
    int max = 0 ; int chh = 0;
    int count[] = new int[a.length];
    for(int i = 0 ; i <a.length ; i++) {
        int ch = a[i];
        count[ch] +=1 ;
    }//for

    for(int i = 0 ; i <a.length ;i++)  {
        int ch = a[i];
        if(count[ch] > max) {max = count[ch] ; chh = ch ;}
    }//for
         System.out.println(chh); 
    }//main
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a java solution --

```java
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3);
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet(list);
        int max = 0;
        int maxtemp;
        int currentNum = 0;
        for (Integer k : set) {
            maxtemp = Math.max(Collections.frequency(list, k), max);
            currentNum = maxtemp != max ? k : currentNum;
            max = maxtemp;
        }
        System.out.println("Number :: " + currentNum + " Occurs :: " + max + " times");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2, 4, 1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 1, 5, 2, 3, 5 };

Long max = Arrays.stream(array).boxed().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i, Collectors.counting())).values()
                .stream().max(Comparator.comparing(Function.identity())).orElse(0L);
```

Comment: This is essentially the same as [Aqil Zeka’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61657891/525036).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   int n;

   int[] arr;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Length of Array");
    n = in.nextInt();
    arr = new int[n];
    System.out.println("Enter Elements in array"); 

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i] = in.nextInt();
    }

    int greatest = arr[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > greatest) {
            greatest = arr[i];
        }

    } 

    System.out.println("Greatest Number " + greatest);

    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (greatest == arr[i]) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Number of Occurance of " + greatest + ":" + count + " times");

    in.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In continuation to the pseudo-code what you've written try the below written code:-

```
public static void fetchFrequency(int[] arry) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> newMap = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>(Collections.reverseOrder());
        int num = 0;
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arry.length; i++) {
            if (newMap.containsKey(arry[i])) {
                count = newMap.get(arry[i]);
                newMap.put(arry[i], ++count);
            } else {
                newMap.put(arry[i], 1);
            }
        }
        Set<Entry<Integer, Integer>> set = newMap.entrySet();
        List<Entry<Integer, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<Entry<Integer, Integer>>(set);
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Entry<Integer, Integer> o1, Entry<Integer, Integer> o2) {
                return (o2.getValue()).compareTo(o1.getValue());
            }
        });

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : list) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " ==== " + entry.getValue());
            break;
        }
        //return num;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i have implemented in java..

```
import java.io.*;
class Prog8
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Input Array Size:");
        int size=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int[] arr= new int[size];
        System.out.println("Input Elements in Array:");
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
            arr[i]=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int max = 0,pos=0,count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            count=0;
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) 
            {
                if (arr[i]==arr[j])
                    count++;
            }
            if (count >=max)
            {
                max = count;
                pos=i;
            }
        }

        if(max==1)
            System.out.println("No Duplicate Element.");
        else
            System.out.println("Element:"+arr[pos]+" Occourance:"+max);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the element with the highest occurrences in an array using java 8 is given below:

```
final Long maxOccurrencesElement = arr.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .max((o1, o2) -> o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue()))
                .get()
                .getKey();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this problem in one loop with without using HashMap or any other data structure in O(1) space complexity.

Initialize two variables count = 0 and max = 0 (or Integer.MIN_VALUE if you have negative numbers in your array)

The idea is you will scan through the array and check the current number,

- if it is less than your current max...then do nothing
- if it is equal to your max ...then increment the count variable
- if it is greater than your max..then update max to current number and set count to 1

Code:

```
int max = 0, count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    int num = array[i];
    if (num == max) {
        count++;
    } else if (num > max) {
        max = num;
        count = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: The array may not be sorted. Read the problem carefully.

Answer (score -1):

Here is Ruby SOlution:

```
def maxOccurence(arr)
  m_hash = arr.group_by(&:itself).transform_values(&:count)
  elem = 0, elem_count = 0
  m_hash.each do |k, v|
    if v > elem_count
        elem = k
        elem_count = v
    end
  end
  "#{elem} occured #{elem_count} times"
end

p maxOccurence(["1", "1","1","1","1","1","5","5","12","12","12","12","12","12","12","12","12","12","8"])
```

output:

```
"12 occured 10 times"
```