# The longest repeating sequence of byte

Tags: java, byte

I have code that should look for the longest repeating sequence. But in this sequence

> 7888885466662716666

and it outputs the first occurrence in the index 1-5 and the second in 2-6, element 8. But 6 must be output since they are duplicate. I thought to go through my sequence of this algorithm along this path

- check if the first character is repeated over the whole string, if
  not
- check if the 2 initial characters are repeated all over, if not
- check if the 3 ...

But I do not know how to take this into my code, can you tell?

```
    private int element;
    private int lastElement;
    private int length;

    private byte[] readByteFromFile(File name) throws IOException {
        return Files.readAllBytes(name.toPath());
    }

    private void searchByte(byte[] byteMass) throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 0; i < byteMass.length; i++) {
                int count = 0;
                for (int j = i + 1; j < byteMass.length; j++) {
                    if (byteMass[i + count] == byteMass[j]) {
                        if (count >= length) {
                            length = count + 1;
                            element = i;
                            lastElement = j - count;
                        }
                        count++;
                    } else {
                        count = 0;
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand your code in relation to your explanation. If I read your explanation you want to find the longest repeated part of a single digit, so for the number `7888885466662716666` that would be `88888`, and it needs to return the inclusive index-range (so `[1,5]` in this case)? But your current problem is that it doesn't output `[1,5]`, but `[2,6]`? [I tried your code]() and it outputs `element=1; lastElement=2; length=4` for input `7888885466662716666`. So I'm not sure what you mean with `2-6`.

Comment: "_But 6 must be output since they are duplicate._" Does this mean you just want the digit that occurs the most in the input (so the result is `6` for input `7888885466662716666`?

Comment: I need to find the longest repeating sequence! 7888885466662716666 - here the longest repeating sequence is 6666, not 88888, since 88888 occur once, unlike 6666) My code displays now what you described in your first message and it's not true)

Comment: Ah ok, now I understand. The longest repeating subsequent of digits that occurs at least two times. Hmm..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my hacked together solution I wrote yesterday...

Basically it checks if `input.charAt(i) == input.charAt(i + 1)` and if so, runs a second loop until they don't match, all the while appending to a `String`, and adds to a `List`. And repeat.

Then check the `List` for the highest occurrence (shamelessly stolen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13553089/6722100))

```
public static void addToList(String input) {
    String temp;
    List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length() - 1; i++) {
        if (input.charAt(i) == input.charAt(i + 1)) {
            temp = String.valueOf(input.charAt(i));
            for (int j = i; j < input.length() - 1; j++) {
                if (input.charAt(j) == input.charAt(j + 1)) {
                    temp += String.valueOf(input.charAt(j + 1));
                    if (j == input.length() - 2) {
                        i = j;
                        if (!temp.isEmpty()) {
                            l.add(temp);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                } else {
                    i = j - 1;
                    if (!temp.isEmpty()) {
                        l.add(temp);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(getHighestOccurences(l));
}

public static String getHighestOccurences(List<String> list) {
    int max = 0;
    int curr;
    String currKey = null;
    Set<String> unique = new HashSet<>(list);
    for (String key : unique) {
        curr = Collections.frequency(list, key);
        if (max < curr) {
            max = curr;
            currKey = key;
        }
    }
    return currKey;
}
```

With your input being `String input = "7888885466662716666";` and calling `addToList(input);` gives an output of:

> 6666

.

**[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/FH4nI2)**

Comment: Ah, that approach isn't too bad either. I like the use of `Collection.frequency` on the list. I see you put every repeating character in the list, and then return the first with a frequency of more than one. +1 from me.

Answer (score 3):

I will be completely honest, I'm not too proud about this solution.. In some other programming languages I'm fairly skilled at I would be able to get the solution pretty easily ([here is a possible implementation in 05AB1E for example](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3OZDK09NOrSu@NAiw0cNu2oPrzy05P9/cwsQMDUxAwIjc0MQBQA)), but in Java it's very hard imho.

I have been able to find a solution by converting the input `byte[]` to a `String` and check its substrings. Performance-wise it's crap however, so I would advice to keep searching for an alternative way to do this.

Regardless, my code is working, so I'll just post it anyway in case parts of it are useful or inspirational:

```
class Main{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Main m = new Main();
    m.test("7888885466662716666".getBytes());
  }

  private void test(byte[] input){
    String result = findLongestRepeatedSubsequence("7888885466662716666".getBytes());
    System.out.println("The longest repeating subsequence in " + new String(input) + " is: " + result);
  }

  private String findLongestRepeatedSubsequence(byte[] byteMass){
    // Convert the bytes to a String:
    String bytesAsString = new String(byteMass);
    // Loop as long as this String has at least 1 character left:
    while(bytesAsString.length() > 0){
      // Split the String into characters, where each character is a loose String of length 1
      String[] charsAsStringArray = bytesAsString.split("");
      int length = charsAsStringArray.length;
      int maxCount = 0;
      int startingIndex = 0;
      // Loop `i` in the range [0, length_of_String_array)
      for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        // Take the substring where the first `i` characters are removed
        String subString = bytesAsString.substring(i);
        String currentChar = charsAsStringArray[i];
        // Count the amount of subsequent times the current character occurs at the start of the substring
        int count = subString.length() - subString.replaceFirst(currentChar+"*", "").length();
        // If this count is larger than our current maxCount:
        if(count > maxCount){
          // Replace the maxCount with this count
          maxCount = count;
          // And set the index where we've found this longest subsequence (`i`) as well
          startingIndex = i;
        }
      }
      // After we've checked all substrings, get the longest subsequence we've found
      String longestSub = bytesAsString.substring(startingIndex, startingIndex + maxCount);
      // Split the entire String with this longest subsequence to get its occurrence-count
      int occurrenceCounter = bytesAsString.split(longestSub, -1).length - 1;
      // If we've found a subsequence that occurs at least twice:
      if(occurrenceCounter > 1){
        // Return it as result
        return longestSub;
      }
      // If this longest subsequence only occurs once:
      else{
        // Remove the first character of this found subsequence from the String
        bytesAsString = bytesAsString.substring(0, startingIndex) +
                        (startingIndex < length-1 ? 
                           bytesAsString.substring(startingIndex + 1)
                         :
                           "");
      }
    }
    // Mandatory return if the input is empty
    return null;
  }
}
```

[**Try it online.**](https://ideone.com/vv23jE) (USEFUL: Contains some additional print lines in comparison to the code above.)

Comment: I wrote a similar ish solution but I felt it too “crap” to post :) basically using substrings it finds if one char is equal to the next, then a subsequent loop until the next char doesn’t equal the previous. Then add to a list. And repeat. Then search the list for the desired result.

Comment: @achAmháin Yeah, I kinda feel the same way with this answer.. The performance is pretty crappy. Converting the `byte[]` to a `String` and checking substrings is a bit of a work-around as well. But since I had finished it I decided to just add some comments and post it anyway.

Comment: @achAmháin In addition, I don't know in what kind of environment OP wants to use it in, so I can't make any judges of how important performance is. Nor do I know how it should behave with more complex test cases (i.e. with `122222233433`; should it find `33` (`1222222[33]4[33]`) or `222` (`1[222][222]33433`). Or with `7773337773331333`; should it find `777` being the first, or `333` having the highest occurrence-count, or both?)